# Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) package of jpegtran (lossless JPEG transformations)

Tags: android, jpg, kotlin, lossless, kmp

jpegtran is a library for lossless JPEG transformations, available mostly as C source code. I want to use it in my open source Android app.

My goal is to make my app easily buildable by newbies who just have a basic Android Studio (and thus can't compile C code).

I think a KMP (Kotlin Multiplatform) package of jpegtran would solve the problem.

Question: Is there such a package? Must be open source.